# Selenium no puede encontrar elemento por nombre de clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Quiero enviar un mensaje a [esta pagina web](https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id=13829371) con Python.

Es por decir hacer lo siguiente pero con python :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso intenté el siguiente script con Selenium:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from selenium import webdriver


api_location = 'http://iphoneapp.spareroom.co.uk'
api_search_endpoint = 'flatshares'
api_details_endpoint = 'flatshares'

location = 'http://www.spareroom.co.uk'
details_endpoint = 'flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id='

def contact_room(room_id):
    url = '{location}/{endpoint}/{id}?format=json'.format(location=api_location, endpoint=api_details_endpoint, id=room_id)
    print(url)
    driver_path = 'C:\Program Files\chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path )  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    # Go to your page url
    driver.get(url)
    # Get button you are going to click by its id ( also you could use find_element_by_css_selector to get element by css selector)
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button button--wide')
    button_element.click()
```

Pero me devuelve :

```
contact_room(14110387)

(roo_env) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\roomfinder>python test_message.py
http://iphoneapp.spareroom.co.uk/flatshares/14110387?format=json

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51038/devtools/browser/401513e8-f221-47f1-ba6b-a7b7f598d839
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_message.py", line 24, in <module>
    contact_room(14110387)
  File "test_message.py", line 21, in contact_room
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button button--wide')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button button--wide"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
```

Mientras que el botón para acceder a la página de mensajería es de la clase `button button--wide`. En efecto, en el codigo fuente hay:

```
<a class="button button--wide" data-ga-event-category="Listing Details" data-ga-event-action="clicked" data-ga-event-label="contact-box-email" href="/flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id=14110387&amp;mode=contact&amp;submode=byemail&amp;flatshare_type=offered&amp;search_id=896264077&amp;search_results=%2Fflatshare%2F%3Fsearch_id%3D896264077%26&amp;city_id=9&amp;featured=&amp;alert_id=&amp;alert_type=&amp;upgrade_required=0&amp;" title="Email advertiser" rel="nofollow"><span><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Message</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo deseas clickear en ese boton, puedes intentarlo a través de `javascript`. de la siguiente manera, aprovechando `execute_script` :

```
browser.execute_script('''
document.getElementsByClassName('emailadvertiser')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
''')
```

`Selenium` no permite seleccionar clases con espacios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar usando el selector xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By #Agrega esto para que puedas usar el By
```

Luego reemplaza

```
button_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button button--wide')
button_element.click()
```

por esto:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '#xpath extraido').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo estoy utilizando así

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

email = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"form-control")
usuario = controlador.find_element(By.NAME,"email")
usuario = controlador.find_element(By.ID,"email--1")
```

Soy nueva en selenium y el curso que estoy viendo utiliza lo que tu estas implementando, la lógica que le veo es que lo que va después del element + (By. + cualquier función que hacías antes pero con mayúsculas + , + el elemento), dejo algunos ejemplos por si te sirve.